# What sites the XCode access when we will publish a app

Tags: xcode, xcode4, app-store, itunes, wireshark

In my company, we have a stupid firewall. It block all itunes.apple.com sites and to publish an app, we have to use our internet. To publish a app, we have to go in this screen in Organizer and press "Share"

[image: In archives tab of organizer to send a app]

Was asked me: what things you have to unblock to publish an app? With my limited knowledge I use the Wireshark and discovery that the program first access the site:

```
http://contentdelivery.itunes.apple.com:443
```

But and after, there are a special port, or a magic thing that the firewall can block? Or it have to unblock only site with `itunes.apple.com` for http and https? I really don't know find it :(

Comment: You are working in a company that publishes iOS apps but blocks the iTunes store?

Comment: YES!!! Do you believe it? There are people in our team that have their our internet modem (like this USB 3G modem), so it don't have the firewall in it.

Comment: Did you find a list of server/ips/urls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try something like [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) to find out, it will pop up a box every time a program tries to access something on the internet - giving you the address and port number.

I find it pretty useful for this and testing connectivity issues in debugging.